# How do I install a cocoapod in mavericks with ruby and Command Line Tools correctly?

Tags: ruby, installation, cocoapods

This is my setup:

Mavericks 10.9.1
Xcode 5.0.2
which ruby returns this:

```
/Users/quique123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
```

but dvm install ruby returns:

```
Already installed ruby-2.1.0.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.0
```

So doesn't this mean I have ruby 2.1.0?

gems list says I have installed cocoa pods & cocoapods-core 0.29.0 and some other gems.

After sudo gem install cocoa pods I get the bunch of fetches and change log and Successfully Installed cocoa pods 0.29.0.  It then parses and installs documentation and when I run pod setup I got:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Setup completed (read-only access)
```

So I created a file from a tutorial:

```
platform :iOS, '7.0'
pod 'Mantle'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

but when I run pod install I get:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoa pods' (>= 0) among 37 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/quique123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/quique123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/quique123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

How do I get the pod to install correctly and why am i getting messages of ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: Looks like you need to use something like `rvm use` and specify the version to your 2.1 version.

Comment: Ok I did dvm --default 2.1.0 and now which ruby says /Users/quique123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby ...Thx!

Comment: Yes I solved it. I had to update my ruby as in this post: http://quique123.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/creating-reactive-cocoa-xcode-project/

Comment: correct command is `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 9):

**If you have rvm installed do not use** `sudo gem install cocoapods`. It creates problems. Follow these steps to fix your cocoapods installation:

1. Uninstall Cocoapods:

   ```
   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   ```
2. Make sure you're on the latest Ruby:

   ```
   which ruby
   ```
3. Install `cocoapods` without `sudo`:

   ```
   gem install cocoapods -V --no-ri --no-rdoc
   # V: Verbose; no-ri,no-rdoc: Do not install documentation
   ```
4. Set up Cocoapods:

   ```
   pod setup
   ```

Should work now.

Comment: gives error installing: You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: This solution is for users who have `rvm` installed ([Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io/))